# How to check if ethereum transaction has been mined

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am using web3 to perform ethereum transactions. I have been able to perform the transaction, but I want to notify the user if the transaction is successful and has been mined. How would i do this in node.js?

I have tried to find ways to use a webhook on the reciever ethereum wallet in order to notify the server if a transaction on the blockchain has been mined. After that i would be able to notify the user.

My last option is to create a multi threaded loop on my server that checks if the transaction hash has been mined.

I am unsure if I should provide any code, as I don’t know if it will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` method to get a receipt for a transaction, or wait for an event generated by a smart contract when your transaction is being executed.

However, you should take into mind that public Ethereum may have forks and you should wait 5-6 blocks to make sure that the transaction will not be dropped along with the "side" fork.